# Performance-enhancing "Battle Drugs"

Tags: history-of, military-sf

The idea of performance-enhancing drugs for soldiers has been kicking around in hard and hard-ish SFF for quite a while. What was the earliest example in SFF fiction? I'm referring to drugs or drug cocktails specifically intended for use by soldiers  (or on them by their own leaders) to improve combat performance. I'm not counting the old standbys like [alcohol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_courage) or [hashish.](http://www.alamut.com/subj/ideologies/alamut/etymolAss.html) I'm ruling out common illegal street drugs like cocaine or meth unless their use is not only legally condoned but they're actually issued as routine combat prep. I'm also ruling out implants unless the primary function of the implants is to stimulate the release of the body's own adrenaline, endorphins, etc.

Comment: For a real life use meth (under the name "Pervitin") was routinely issued to German soldiers in WWII as combat prep (and undoubtedly other armies had something similar), so I don't think SF authors had to stretch their imagination to come up with that.

Comment: I can't recall the exact name of the plant, but there's a particular moss which when boiled and ingested can result in a manic state, and is believed to have been used to generate the famed Viking berserker behaviors.

Comment: Are  you asking about the earliest example in SFF or real life?

Comment: using "sacred herbs" before battle was quite common in many ancient cultures...

Comment: Encounter at Farpoint, the first episode of Star Trek: TNG is immediately what I thought of but surely somebody like Phillip K. Dick toyed with this idea before 1986: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X3o1Jzt4A0w&t=55

Comment: @NKCampbell Dune comes immediately to mind. Timothy Zahn's Blackcollar from '83.

Comment: @NKCampbell Phillip K Dick certainly has explored the idea but as far as I remember it was Mars colonists, not soldiers that were using the drug, so not really a "battle drug"

Comment: @ventsyv - the Freemen didn't really use spice as an extra battle aid though, they were pretty much awash in it to begin with no? It's been a few years since I'd read it - should go dust it off

Comment: @NKCampbell it's been many years for me as well. I thought it was the spice that made them superior fighters, and yes, they were using it all the time.

Comment: Starship Troopers, but I don't have the book available for a quote. The suits had built-in drug dispensers.

Comment: @ventsyv: As fascinating as the real life examples are, I was looking for fictional battle drugs in SFF works.

Comment: Starship troopers was published 6 years before dune. both are good examples. The heightened awareness and geriatric effects of mélange would be a boon to any fighting force. There is a lesser known drug in the dune universe called "semuta" which had a musical element. I don't know if it was performance enhancing, But the Baron Vladimir Harkonnen liked that his Captain of the Guard, Nefud, was addicted to it because it gives the Barron power over him. I'd like to know the nature of the drugs used in Starship troopers, are they pain killers, steroids, ect?

Answer (score 2):

If you'd take the historical information (based on [research rather than story](http://www.historyextra.com/article/feature/viking-berserkers-facts-really-exist)) then Viking Berserkers would be one of the earliest (Romans wrote about them in the first century CE)

According to the most popular theory, they were ingesting [fly amanita mushroom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amanita_muscaria) (or to be more precise - one of them was eating the raw mushroom, the rest was drinking his urine, to purify the undesired toxic effects) and with help of meditation they were "taken over by the animal spirit" (bear or a wolf).

As for the effects - they would howl like wild beasts, foamed at the mouth, and gnawed the iron rim of their shields. According to belief, during these fits they were immune to steel and fire, and made great havoc in the ranks of the enemy. When the fever abated they were weak and tame. Accounts can be found in the sagas

Comment: https://skeptoid.com/episodes/4557 Actually the berserkers may have been suffering PTSD